# CodeIgniter .. Video upload problem using crud

Tags: codeigniter, video, file-upload, grocery-crud

I am facing a strange problem in video upload field, when I upload it after the upload progress percentage is completed, then it disappears without any error message, and if I save it the field is saved empty, thus the file is not uploaded. I have tried .mp4 files and the file size was under 100 MB that I have configured in grocery_crud.php.
I've used:

$crud->set_field_upload

I've tried to upload image without any problem, is it using to upload just images ? so how could I upload a video using it?

Comment: did you check php post_max_size  and upload_max_filesize? would a 100MB image work? Any error messages?

Comment: Thanks I've just Added it, I'm so beginner in php.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to [Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel)

I've just added :

php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_input_time 3600
php_value max_execution_time 3600

to my .htaccess and the problem Solved :)